# Query for achieve max row in group by?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as following:

```
id  |   name    |   score
-------------------------
1   |   Alex    |    10
2   |   Jim     |    20
3   |   Ming    |   12
4   |   Alex    |   15
5   |   Alex    |   17
6   |   Ming    |   11
```

I want a query with following result:

```
id  |   name    |   score
-------------------------
5   |   Alex    |    17
2   |   Jim     |    20
3   |   Ming    |   12
```

Is there any solution for achieve above result by a query?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried, what is the problem, what is the basis for your desired result? You have enough rep to know how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more efficient, memory-wise, than the `row_number()` approach.

```
with test(id, name, score) as (
  select 1,'Alex',10 from dual union all
  select 2,'Jim',20 from dual union all
  select 3,'Ming',12 from dual union all
  select 4,'Alex',15 from dual union all
  select 5,'Alex',17 from dual union all
  select 6,'Ming',11 from dual
)
select max(id) keep ( dense_rank first order by score desc, id asc) id, name, max(score) score
from test
group by name;
```

To demonstrate the efficiency, you can run these two queries in any Oracle database:

### Query #1 - `row_number` approach

```
select object_id, object_type, last_ddl_time from 
(select row_Number() over ( partition by object_type order by last_ddl_time desc, object_id asc) rn, object_id, object_type, last_ddl_time from dba_objects ) 
where rn = 1;
```

### Query #2 - `max() keep` approach

```
select max(object_id) keep ( dense_rank first order by last_ddl_time desc, object_id asc) object_id, object_type, max(last_ddl_time)
from dba_objects
group by object_type;
```

On my database, both queries required 188,000 buffer gets.  But query #1 required 28 meg of memory to execute, while query #2 required next to nothing.  After running each query a few times (for fairness - to get everything into buffers), query #2 ran slightly faster (3.52 seconds vs 5.11 seconds).  But many things can affect wall-clock runtime.  The relative memory usage is the more compelling data.

#### WITHOUT ORACLE FUNCTIONS

```
with test(id, name, score) as (
  select 1,'Alex',10 from dual union all
  select 2,'Jim',20 from dual union all
  select 3,'Ming',12 from dual union all
  select 4,'Alex',15 from dual union all
  select 5,'Alex',17 from dual union all
  select 6,'Ming',11 from dual
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.score
from test t1
where not exists ( SELECT 'higher score, or higher ID if same score, for the same name'
                   FROM test t2
                   WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                   AND   ( t2.score > t1.score OR ( t2.score = t1.score AND t2.id > t1.id ) ) );
```

Comment: @MJM you should have a secondary sort other than `score` to break ties.  Otherwise, it will be ambiguous which `id` you will get for a given `name`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This way is ok but I want is there any way with standard SQL (without oracle functions)

Comment: Updated my answer with an approach that doesn't use Oracle functions.  The price you pay for not using Oracle's features is performance.  This won't run as well as my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
with test(id, name, score) as (
  select 1,'Alex',10 from dual union all
  select 2,'Jim',20 from dual union all
  select 3,'Ming',12 from dual union all
  select 4,'Alex',15 from dual union all
  select 5,'Alex',17 from dual union all
  select 6,'Ming',11 from dual
)
select id, name, score
from (
        select row_number() over (partition by name order by score desc) as RN,
               id, name, score
        from test
     )
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This way is ok but I want is there any way with standard SQL (without oracle functions)